# Errorlevel check does not work in batch file

Tags: batch-file, errorlevel

In the code below, the errorlevel check never works. So if a failure happens no email goes out. The Powershell command is correct and works outside this construct. I also tried a direct check: If %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0

But that doesn't work either.

Any ideas? Thanks!

```
@echo off
set day=-1
echo >"%temp%\%~n0.vbs" s=DateAdd("d",%day%,now) : d=weekday(s)
echo>>"%temp%\%~n0.vbs" WScript.Echo year(s)^& right(100+month(s),2)^&            right(100+day(s),2)
for /f %%a in ('cscript /nologo "%temp%\%~n0.vbs"') do set "result=%%a"
del "%temp%\%~n0.vbs"
set "YYYY=%result:~0,4%"
set "MM=%result:~4,2%"
set "DD=%result:~6,2%"
set "dt=%mm%-%dd%-%yyyy%"

"LogParser.exe" "SELECT * INTO tblIisLog FROM \\iislogs\%dt%\*.log" -i:iisw3c -o:SQL -    oConnString:"Driver=SQL Server;Server=servername; Database=IISDB;Trusted_Connection=yes" -    createTable:ON
SET /a RC=%ERRORLEVEL%

IF %RC% NEQ 0
(

   powershell.exe -executionpolicy unrestricted -command "send-mailmessage -from     'me@abc.com' -to 'me@abc.com' -subject 'test' -body 'testing' -smtpServer 'smtpserv.com'"

)
```

Comment: Left paren must be in same `IF` line: `IF %RC% NEQ 0 (`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that LogParser.exe does return an errorlevel, this should work and is more concise to boot:

```
LogParser.exe "SELECT blah, blah, blah..."
if errorlevel 1 powershell.exe -executionpolicy ...
```

Comment: The thing is I think it does, because I printed it out to a text file, it is 54. I'll try what you said.

Answer (score 0):

I've read precisely one article about `logparser` which claimd that it did indeed return `errorlevel` non-zero on error.

I suspect that there has been an assignment made to a user variable `errorlevel`. Whereas `if errorlevel 1 ...` would work because the `if errorlevel` construct operates on the actual `errorlevel`, any approach using `%errorlevel%` examines the user-set variables first. Assigning any value to `errorlevel` or its chums (`date`, `time`, `random` etc.) can lead to such unexpected results (but can be useful whilst debugging - you can set one of these "variables" to a known value)

The really easy 2-second way of testing this theory (which may or may not be a cure) is to simply include the line

```
set "errorlevel="
```

just before the `logparser` call. Much quicker than any technical analysis and argument.

Comment: Ah - and the syntax error. Nevertheless, I'll leave this as a foil to such problems.